# Buscar todas las preguntas/respuestas que he publicado en la red de Stack Exchange

Tags: soporte, respuesta, stackexchange, data-explorer, búsqueda

## Pregunta

Al responder una pregunta recordé que ya había publicado algunas cosas que valdría la pena integrar, pero estas publicaciones están en Stack Overflow en inglés, Web Applications o Stack Overflow en español. Lo primero que intenté fue buscar usando palabras clave en [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) pero no fue tan sencillo como esperaba.

Sólo por ver que pasaba intente usar [user:me](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame) el cual funciona bien en el buscador de cada sitio, pero esto no funcionó asumo que debido a que en cada sitio de la red se tiene una cuenta distinta, por ejemplo, en este sitio soy el usuario `65`, en Web Applications el `88163` y en Stack Overflow el `1595451`. Tampoco funciona usar usuario y el número de usuario, por ejemplo `user:65`.

Se que está la opción de crear un **filtro**, pero me pregunto si es posible **mediante el buscador** ya que me parece que sería más ágil y en ocasiones las búsquedas circunstanciales, por ejemplo, al responder una pregunta en particular.

En Meta Stack Exchange encontré preguntas sobre cómo buscar en un sitio en específico pero no en toda la red.

¿Existe un operador de búsqueda o algo así para buscar todas las publicaciones propias en [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) ?

---

## Progreso

---

Mariano respondió con la sugerencia de usar un query de SEDE, lo cual parece ser la solución óptima con la salvedad que SEDE se actualiza una vez por semana.

Como creo será la mejor respuesta la he aceptado de una vez. De todas formas, los detalles que surjan los iré compartiendo en comentarios y [progreso](https://sites.google.com/a/rubenrivera.mx/preguntas-en-stack-exchange/progreso).

---

Hecho:

- Cree [un sitio de google](https://sites.google.com/a/rubenrivera.mx/preguntas-en-stack-exchange/) y agregué ahí tres máquinas de búsqueda personalizadas, todo, sólo español y sólo inglés.
- Para reducir el número de actualizaciones en esta página en el sitio referido previamente se incluyó [una página](https://sites.google.com/a/rubenrivera.mx/preguntas-en-stack-exchange/progreso) de tipo avisos con el nombre "Progreso".

Por hacer:

- Limitar los resultados a sólo las de un usuario en particular, que puede ser alguno de los usuarios notables.

---

En su respuesta Luiggi comparte muy buenas observaciones. Señala varias cosas que pasé por alto y definitivamente son muy útiles como parte de la búsqueda/investigación. Se me ocurre que "la solución definitiva" va a ser lo mismo que ha hecho SE, hacer una "google custom search" o bien usar el RSS de un filtro.

---

## Anexo

Resultados de buscar user:me
Nota: Yo no he publicado ninguno de esos resultados.

[image: Resultados de buscar user:me]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como [te respondió @LuiggiMendoza](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2173/127), la búsqueda en [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) utiliza el motor de Google, por lo que no se pueden utilizar los parámetros de búsqueda de los sitios.

Por eso, armé un query en SEDE:

#### Ver en: [Búsqueda de publicaciones de un usuario en todos los sitios](http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/683547/busqueda-de-publicaciones-de-un-usuario-en-todos-los-sitios)

- Toma el Id global de tu usuario (buscalo en tu perfil en [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/))
- Realiza una búsqueda del tipo

  ```sql
  where Body  like '%palabra%'
     or Title like '%palabra%'
  ```

---

**Código** (aunque conviene verlo en el enlace de arriba):

```sql
-- AccountId: AccountId "Id de perfil de red del usuario (obtenida en Perfil > Perfil de red)"
-- Like: Like "Término de búsqueda. Usar % para coincidir con cualquier caracter."
-- OrLike: Or Like "Término de búsqueda alternativo. Usar -1 para ignorar. Usar % para coincidir con cualquier caracter."
-- AndLike2: And Like "Otro término de búsqueda obligatorio. Usar -1 para ignorar. Usar % para coincidir con cualquier caracter."
-- AndLike3: And Like "Otro término de búsqueda obligatorio. Usar -1 para ignorar. Usar % para coincidir con cualquier caracter."

DECLARE @accountid AS nvarchar(12) = cast(##AccountId:int## as nvarchar)
DECLARE @searchtext AS nvarchar(max) = ##Like:string?%palabra%##
DECLARE @searchtext2 AS nvarchar(max) = ##OrLike:string?-1##
DECLARE @searchtextand2 AS nvarchar(max) = ##AndLike2:string?-1##
DECLARE @searchtextand3 AS nvarchar(max) = ##AndLike3:string?-1##

-- Forked from: http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/355774/cross-site-query-template
-- Create cursor for list of sites
DECLARE sites CURSOR FOR
  SELECT name
  FROM sys.databases
  WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb', 'Data.StackExchange')
-- And declare some variables
DECLARE @sitedbname AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @sitehostname AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @ispersitemeta AS bit

DECLARE @query AS nvarchar(max)
CREATE TABLE #out (
  Sitio nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
  -- ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
  -- COLUMN NAMES WANT TO ADD SHOULD GO HERE   
  Puntaje int,
  [Título] nvarchar(max),
  Fecha date
  -- ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
)
-- These variables are for the SPOOKY HOSTNAME GENERATION CODE
DECLARE @spooky_string AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @spooky_delimiter AS char(1) = '.'
DECLARE @spooky_xml AS xml
DECLARE @spooky_result AS nvarchar(max)

-- Step through cursor
OPEN sites
FETCH NEXT FROM sites INTO @sitedbname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- BEGIN SPOOKY HOSTNAME GENERATION CODE ------------------------------------
  -- adapted from <http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/256747/> -
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SET @spooky_string = @sitedbname
  SET @spooky_xml = CAST(('<X>' + REPLACE(@spooky_string, @spooky_delimiter, '</X><X>') + '</X>') AS xml)
  SET @spooky_result = ''

  SELECT
    C.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') AS [Piece],
    C.value('for $i in . return count(../*[. << $i]) + 1', 'int') AS [Index]
  INTO #spooky_pieces
  FROM @spooky_xml.nodes('X') AS X(C)

  SELECT @spooky_result = COALESCE(@spooky_result + '.', '') + [Piece]
  FROM #spooky_pieces
  ORDER BY [Index] DESC

  DROP TABLE #spooky_pieces

  SET @sitehostname = 'http://' + RIGHT(@spooky_result, LEN(@spooky_result)-1) + '.com'
  SET @ispersitemeta = (CASE WHEN @sitedbname LIKE '%Meta%' AND @sitedbname != 'StackExchange.Meta' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

  ----------------------------------------
  -- HERE COME THE SPOOKY SPECIAL CASES --
  ----------------------------------------
  -- Meta MathOverflow doesn't have a redirect; see <http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215071/224428>
  IF @sitedbname = 'StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta' SET @sitehostname = 'http://Meta.MathOverflow.net'
  -- For some reason probably involving the AVP/Audio/Video/Sound hullabaloo, there is 
  -- still a StackExchange.Audio DB that's getting updated. http://audio.stackexchange.com/
  -- no longer exists, so we use Video.SE for the hostname instead.
  IF @sitedbname = 'StackExchange.Audio' SET @sitehostname = 'http://Video.StackExchange.com'
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- END SPOOKY HOSTNAME GENERATION CODE --------------------------------------
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  -- ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
  -- CODE YOU WANT TO ADD SHOULD GO HERE
  -- for example,
  SET @query = '
    USE [' + @sitedbname + ']

    INSERT INTO #out
    SELECT
           ''' + @sitehostname + '|' + @sitedbname + ''' [Sitio],

            p.Score Puntaje,
            ''' + @sitehostname + '/q/'' + cast(p.Id as nvarchar) + ''|'' 
              + case when p.PostTypeId = 1 then
                     p.Title 
                else (select Title from Posts where Id = p.ParentId)
                 end [Título],
            p.CreationDate Fecha
       from Posts p
       left join Users u
         on p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
      where u.AccountId = ' + @accountid + '
        and p.PostTypeId <= 2
        and (
              (
                p.Body like ''' + @searchtext + ''' or p.Title like ''' + @searchtext + '''
                or  (''' + @searchtext2 + ''' <> ''-1'' and (p.Body like ''' + @searchtext2 + ''' or p.Title like ''' + @searchtext2 + '''))
              )
              and (''' + @searchtextand2 + ''' = ''-1'' or p.Body like ''' + @searchtextand2 + ''' or p.Title like ''' + @searchtextand2 + ''')
              and (''' + @searchtextand3 + ''' = ''-1'' or p.Body like ''' + @searchtextand3 + ''' or p.Title like ''' + @searchtextand3 + ''')
            ) 
    '
  EXEC sp_executesql @query
  -- ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑

  FETCH NEXT FROM sites INTO @sitedbname
END
CLOSE sites
DEALLOCATE sites

-- Reap results (also optional)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  #out


ORDER BY Fecha desc
```

Comment: ¿Cómo debería "encodear" los parámetros? Por ejemplo,`%recalculation% %formulas%`.  Quiero buscar las preguntas que he publicado sobre recálculo  de fórmulas en las hojas de cálculo de google.

Comment: Ya. `?AccountId=1745021&Like=%25recalculation%25%20%25sheets%25`

Comment: @Rubén Esto devuelve las que tienen `recalc` *seguido* de `formula`: `%recalc%formula%`, pero también deberías buscar `%formula%recalc%`. Si te es importante buscar que tenga 2 términos en cualquier orden, puedo editar el query en SEDE.

Comment: ¡Ah!. Pues sí, lo ideal sería que operara lo más similar posible a una búsqueda de Google (se me olvidan muchas cosas, pero como buscar en Google no, jeje)

Comment: @Rubén http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/683547/busqueda-de-publicaciones-de-un-usuario-en-todos-los-sitios?AccountId=1745021&Like=%25recalc%25&OrLike=-1&AndLike2=%25formula%25&AndLike3=-1

Comment: Fantástico, aprecio enormemente las atenciones. Antes de que nos vayan  a borrar los comentarios por "muy conversadores" ya lo he "documentado" de forma muy suscinta en una [nueva entrada](https://sites.google.com/a/rubenrivera.mx/preguntas-en-stack-exchange/progreso/querytipogoogle) en "progreso".

Comment: Hice un "feature request" en Meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297358/289691

Answer (score 1):

El resultado de la búsqueda en https://stackexchange.com/search es distinto al de la búsqueda en los sitios puesto que se maneja por Google y no por el motor de StackExchange. Esto se puede ver debajo del campo de tipo de ordenamiento con el logo *powered by Google Custom Search*. Imagen de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debido a esto, lo más que pude poner es user:Luiggi Mendoza is:question pero aparecen todas las preguntas donde está mi nombre de alguna manera, p.e. preguntas donde yo he puesto un comentario o donde voté a cierre y aparece mi nombre.

Al revisar los queries en https://data.stackexchange.com/ parece que cada sitio tiene su propia base de datos, por lo cual tampoco se puede construir un query para buscar las preguntas para tu usuario específico en múltiples partes de todos los sitios.

La recomendación que daría para este caso sería o buscar sitio por sitio (en inglés hay una expresión para esto: bummer!). Por otro lado, podrías tratar de ver los parámetros de las búsquedas en Google para refinar la búsqueda lo máximo posible.

Comment: Actualizado, aunque creo que no es lo mejor que existe.

Comment: Muy buenas observaciones ya que señalas varias cosas que pasé por alto y definitivamente son muy útiles como parte de la búsqueda/investigación. Se me ocurre que "la solución definitiva" va a ser lo mismo que ha hecho SE, hacer una "google custom search". Bueno, voy a dejar "reposar un rato" este tema para atender otros asuntos.

Comment: Hice un "feature request" en Meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297358/289691

Answer (score 1):

Recién encontré una pregunta similar en Meta SE: [Searching my own questions & answers over all stack exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102936/289691).

La pregunta es del 2011 y cuenta con una respuesta de [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino) quien según su propio perfil es el Director de Desarrollo de la Comunidad de Stack Exchange.

Al igual que lo señalado por Luiggi y Mariano en sus respuesta, la búsqueda en el sitio Stack Exchange usa una Máquina de Búsqueda Personalizada de Google (CSE por sus siglas en inglés).

Indagando un poco sobre CSE es posible limitar los resultados usando tipos de esquemas de Schema.org. Por lo que he podido ver hasta ahora, las páginas de Stack Exchange usan varios tipos de los cuales me parece interesantes `QAPage`, `Question` y `Answer`. El primer tipo incluye las páginas de preguntas más recientes de las etiquetas y posiblemente otras además la segunda se usa en páginas de preguntas, y la tercera en elementos que corresponden a respuestas.

<s>Todavía no identifico si existe una forma de limitar las preguntas de un autor en particular</s>. Recién llegué a [Google Authorship Changes: What You Need to Know](https://www.semrush.com/blog/google-authorship-changes-need-know/) lo cual a su vez me llevó a la sugerencia de agregar los sitos que uno colabora en la sección de "Contributor to" del perfil de Google+, pero esa sección no la encuentro en el nuevo Google+, la explicación está en [Autoría en la búsqueda web](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6083347?hl=es): Ya no se permite.

Al momento, me parece que la mejor opción es usar el query que pone Mariano en su respuesta.

Recién publiqué un "feature request" : [Make more precise the post searching by autor on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297358/289691)